# How to Insert CSV Table to Mysql Database?

Tags: php, database, csv

I have a simple uploading page that will allow a user to upload CSV file into the server.

After the uploading, the page will display the CSV file into an html table format

Code to Display CSV File to HTML:

```
<?php
echo "<table class='tbl1'>\n\n";

echo "<tr>";
echo "<th>GOUP NO</th>";
echo "<th>PID CODE</th>";
echo "<th>ID CODE</th>";
echo "<th>DESCRIPTION</th>";
echo "</tr>";

$f = fopen("upload\micro_center.csv", "r");
while (($line = fgetcsv($f)) !== false) {
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach ($line as $cell) {
            echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($cell) . "</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>\n";
}
fclose($f);
echo "\n</table>";
?>
```

I want to add a query on how to insert the data in the CSV file or displayed html table into MSSQL database.

Note: Table headers and Database Table Columns are with the same name

CSV File:

```
0,G068,CNDLDS,Candelaria District
0,CNDLDS,CNDLDSA,Babancal ES
0,CNDLDS,CNDLDSB,Binabalian ES
0,CNDLDS,CNDLDSC,Candelaria Central
0,CNDLDS,CNDLDSD,Catol ES
```

Thank You for your answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the below code:

```
//get the csv file 
$file = $_FILES[csv][tmp_name];  // your csv file here
$handle = fopen($file,"r"); 

//loop through the csv file and insert into database 
do { 
    if ($data[0]) { 
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO your table (GOUP_NO, PID_CODE, ID_CODE, DESCRIPTION) VALUES 
            ( 
                '".addslashes($data[0])."', 
                '".addslashes($data[1])."', 
                '".addslashes($data[2])."',
                '".addslashes($data[3])."'  
            ) 
        "); 
    } 
} while ($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",","'")); 
//
```